# read CSV to Map[String,String]

Tags: scala

I need to read (from input stream) a 2 column csv and return a Map.

File `score.txt`:

```
player1,21
player2,99
player3,143
```

Non-working code:

```
Try(Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"$RelativePath/$fileName")).getLines().map(_.split(","))) match {
      case Success(scoreMap) => scoreMap
      case Failure(err) => //TODO add throw exception
    }
```

The first line returns an `Iterator[Array[String]]`, but how do I return a `Map[String,String]`?

P.S. I've tried various "CSV to MAP" solutions on stack, each one looks like it's written in its own language and all have errors I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: `.map(_.split(",")).collect{case Array(k,v) => k->v}.toMap`

Comment: Nice answer @jwvh. I wrote by accessing indexes of array

Comment: jwvh: This code throws a "java.lang.NullPointerException" for me. Couldn't find why

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your input that you receive from the following line

```
Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"$RelativePath/$fileName")).getLines().map(_.split(","))
```

is in the following format

```
val inputArr: Iterator[Array[String]] = Array(
  Array("player1", "21"),
  Array("player2", "99"),
  Array("player3", "143")
).toIterator
```

To convert this `Iterator[Array[String]]` to `Map[String, String]`, you can write the following function

```
val output = inputArr.map{ arr =>
  arr(0) -> arr(1)
}.toMap
```

It will give you an output as

```
output: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(player1 -> 21, player2 -> 99, player3 -> 143)
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: I get a NullPointer exception. not sure if the issue is with the code or accessing the file...

Comment: Its difficult to explain from my end why you are getting a null pointer exception. I need to look at your code in that case.